# VBA EXCEL formula in a String

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I would like to put into a STRING the following formula

```
Dim stringAppoggio As String
Dim myMonth As String

myMonth = "January 2020"

stringAppoggio="=DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(01-'&myMonth&'-&YEAR(myMonth)),0))"
```

It doesn't really give me a syntax error, but I don't see the result of the formula in the String

Thank you

Comment: You used single quotes around your first `myMonth` variable, then you didn't use quotes at all on your second one. Also, you sure about the formula? Try to `Debug.Print` the line first and see what it returns =)

Comment: ah yes! My formula was wrong, but I read on the net that if I give it: day, month and year, the formula recognize it, so I tried to give only month and year, but It doesn't seems to works...

Comment: Can you help me out with the formula? Should I split **myMonth** into to string with only month and year?

Comment: What is it you really want the formula to do in the end? Do you want to return the last day of "January 2020"? Notice your variable currently hold a month and a year in it's string!

Comment: No I would like the formula to return the number of days of the given month. Ex January 2020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as per my comment, there are a few mistakes here:

- You have used single quotes instead of double quotes to seperate your variable from VBA formula syntax
- You have forgotten the quotes at all around your second `myMonth` variable
- You have created a formula that simply won't work

Keep in mind, your variable is not just a month but a string holding a month and year > `"January 2020"`, therefor `DATEVALUE` won't need the `01-` and `YEAR(myMonth)` to work. Let me explain:

```
=DATEVALUE("January 2020")
```

Will return `Integer` 43831, or in other words: `1-1-2020`. Then secondly, `EOMONTH` will return the end of that same month as an `Integer`, whereas `DAY` will return the number of that day. So your formula would read:

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("January 2020"),0))
```

Now to write this in VBA:

```
Dim stringAppoggio As String
Dim myMonth As String

myMonth = "January 2020"
stringAppoggio = "=DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(""" & myMonth & """),0))"
```

You can check that it works:

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("=DAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(""" & myMonth & """),0))")
```

<sub>**Note:** See the triple quotes? That's because we need to feed `DATEVALUE` a string within quotes to work, otherwise it wouldn't be a string and will return an error</sub>

Comment: i agree. nicely explained :)

Comment: If you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189425/excel-vba-run-formula-via-macro

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim stringAppoggio As String
Dim myMonth As String

myMonth = Chr(34) & "January 2020" & Chr(34)

stringAppoggio = "=DAY(EDATE(" & myMonth & ",1)-DAY(" & myMonth & "))"
```