# EXCEL VBA run formula via MACRO

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I had already asked a question like this before but I'm really bad at VBA formula.

Here is my formula:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CellRange).formula = "=IF(Sheet2!E$4=X;CONCATENATE(Sheet3! """ & myString """, Not defined)"
```

> Run-time error 1004: error defined by the application or object

myString is a **STRING** and contains the address of a cell.

I've used to follow the explanation from my previous question [A question with a really good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387518/vba-excel-formula-in-a-string)

But It didn't worked this time. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`. Then check your parentheses.... Always helps to `Debug.Print` what you expect the formula to be before trying to write it to a cell.

Comment: How should I check a formula with `Debug.Print`? I should put it in a string before I debug?

Comment: `Debug.Print "=IF(Sheet2!E$4=X;CONCATENATE(Sheet3! """ & myString """, Not defined)"` then check the Immediate Window. The right-hand side is a string.

Comment: Maybe the `"`'s something like so `"=IF(Sheet2!E$4=X;CONCATENATE(Sheet3!" & myString  & ", ""Not defined"")"` there is no false part of your `if` either.

Comment: So thanks to `Debug.Print` I figured out the meaning of my existence and how to write PROPERLY the Formula. @BigBen your a master!

Answer (score 1):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(cellrange).Formula = _
  "=IF(Sheet2!E$4=""X"",Sheet3!" & myString & ", ""Not defined"")"
```

Comment: @Plutian Hi. I thought this answer was the corrected version of the line of code in the question. I could write a detailed explanation, but my English is not good. This text was created with Google Translate https://translate.google.com

Comment: No problem, it is more of a suggestion. It is more important for the asker than for me. I will remove my comment.